# How to use SwiftType Search api for OR case?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch

I am using SwiftType search api for implementing search in my web application. I want to cater a case where I need all my products either with DisableBuyButton set to true OR products with Price = 0. I basically need the products that satisfy either of these cases in one search.

I did this;

```
var requestData = new SwifttypeRequest
{
    engine_key = engineKey,
    q = query,
    spelling = _elasticSearchSetting.Spelling,
    document_types = documentTypes,
    filters = new Filters
    {
        prolineproducts = new ProlineProducts
        {
            DisableBuyButton = "True",
            Price = new Price
            {
                type = "range",
                from = 0,
                to = 0
            },
            Manufacturer = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(manufacturer) ? manufacturer : null,
            Category = categoryNames != null ? categoryNames : null
        }
    },
    search_fields = new SearchFields
    {
        prolineproducts = searchFields
    },
    sort_field = new SortField { prolineproducts = orderBy switch { (int)ProductSortingEnum.Position => "_score", (int)ProductSortingEnum.NameAsc => "Name", (int)ProductSortingEnum.NameDesc => "Name", (int)ProductSortingEnum.PriceAsc => "Price", (int)ProductSortingEnum.PriceDesc => "Price", (int)ProductSortingEnum.SkuAsc => "Sku", (int)ProductSortingEnum.SkuDsc => "Sku", (int)ProductSortingEnum.CreatedOn => "CreatedOn", _ => "_score" } },
    sort_direction = new SortDirection { prolineproducts = orderBy switch { (int)ProductSortingEnum.Position => "desc", (int)ProductSortingEnum.NameAsc => "asc", (int)ProductSortingEnum.NameDesc => "desc", (int)ProductSortingEnum.PriceAsc => "asc", (int)ProductSortingEnum.PriceDesc => "desc", (int)ProductSortingEnum.SkuAsc => "asc", (int)ProductSortingEnum.SkuDsc => "desc", (int)ProductSortingEnum.CreatedOn => "desc", _ => "desc" } },
    per_page = perPage,
    page = currentPage
};
```

But this is doing an AND operation on the filters.

Help me achieve my requirement.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57395024/2892829) answer your question?